# How to search for a string in a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have to search the first column in a csv file for a string from `input()`. I know the string is there in the first column, but my search function is hitting the `else` statement. Can anyone see the error here? I've already thrown in a few debug print statements to check things like `filepath` and the value of `symbol` and everything looks correct.

```
def search(symbol, indir="C:\\Conc"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    with open("out.csv", "r") as theFile:
        reader = csv.reader(theFile, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == symbol:
                print(row)
            else:
                print("Stock is not in database, please try again")
                menu()
```

Comment: Imagine the execution in your head: First row of the loop, the first element is not the symbol. What will happen? We go to the else and leave the function. You might want to add a `break` in the `if` and move the `else` to be at the level of the `for`. That way only if the symbol was not found in **any** row it will go to `menu`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def search(symbol, indir="C:\\Conc"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    with open("out.csv", "r") as theFile:
        reader = csv.reader(theFile, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == symbol:
                print(row)
                break
        else:
                print("Stock is not in database, please try again")
                menu()
```

Your code doesn't work because after the first iteration if the program doesn't find the symbol it will execute the else block.
My code will execute the else block if the program did not find the symbol in any row otherwise the loop will be broken and the else block skipped.

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Oh man, that's embarrassing having the else statement indented too far. So many people have told me about the importance of whitespace and indenting in python, yet I didn't see it. Thank you for your help, much appreciated